# Get access token in CommerceJs

Tags: next.js, commerce

I am unable to get an access token in CommerJS. Every time I get a message like

> Token "e1c8a9bf-8faf-4343-a6b3-1089c6861391" not found, or no longer valid.

```
 const { id } = router.query

const commerce = new Commerce(props.commercePublicKey);

commerce.customer.getToken(id)
    .then((jwt) => console.log(jwt))
    .catch(error=>console.log(error.data)
);
```

Comment: Looks like you are using a wrong key try this demo key `pk_184625ed86f36703d7d233bcf6d519a4f9398f20048ec` from [docs](https://commercejs.com/docs/guides/nextjs-integration).

Comment: Its not working. 'Token "pk_184625ed86f36703d7d233bcf6d519a4f9398f20048ec" not found, or no longer valid.',

Comment: Since you are using Next.js maybe try using `CommerceSDK` instead of `Commerce`, like [official integration guide](https://commercejs.com/docs/guides/nextjs-integration/) suggests